# Ack regex on filenames

Tags: regular-expression, perl, ack

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6738175/283296):

> Q: My understanding is that ack uses Perl-derivative regular expressions, is that correct?
>
> A: Yes. In fact, ack is written in Perl and just forwards the expressions 
>       to the internal engine.

Now, I have a file under the current directory called:

`media_group_xml_producer.py`

when I do:

```
> ack -n '.*group.*producer.*'
```

or more directly:

```
> ack -n --python '.*group.*producer.*'
```

I don't get any results. As far as I can tell, the regex should match this file. Why does it miss it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### If grepping over filenames in the current directory is all you need

ack matches the contents of files, not their name. To find files whose name matches a regex, run ack over the list of filenames:

```
ls | ack '.*group.*producer.*'
```

What you did, namely

```
ack -n '.*group.*producer.*'
```

will instead look for files in the current directory *containing* something matching the regex.

### If you want to run your regex over full filenames including the subdirectory path

`ls` won't cut it, because it doesn't have an option to print the path along with the filename. Instead, use `tree` with flags `-i` (don't print indentation lines) and `-f` (print full filenames).

```
tree -if | ack 'shepherd.*\.pyc?'
```

returns

```
./models/shepherd.py
./models/shepherd.pyc
./services/shepherd-related/flock_of_sheep.py
./services/shepherd-related/flock_of_sheep.pyc
```

All the above works with `grep` as well as `ack`, of course. But `ack` is definitely nicer in every way. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand what `ack` does. It is a `grep`-analog, not a `find`-analog. It searches through the contents of files for the given pattern and not for file names matching the pattern. You should instead use

```
find -regex '.*group.*producer.*'
```

Or

```
find -name '*group*producer*'
```

If you insist on using `ack` (though I see no point in doing so), you can parse its output to get your file:

```
$ ack -f | ack '.*group.*producer.*' 
media_group_xml_producer.py
```

The `ack -f` will just print all files that would be searched without actually searching for anything and the second one will print file names that match your regex.

Comment: `ack -f | ack regex` is such a common construct that it now has its own flag, -g: `ack -g regex`.